# Why Opencv DNN based (caffe) face detector failed to find faces?

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

By using OpenCV version 4.2.0 in c++ (VS 2019) I created project which performs face detection on the given image. I used Opencv's DNN face detector which uses `res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel` model to detect faces. Below is the code of that function:

```
//variables which are used in function
const double inScaleFactor = 1.0;
const cv::Scalar meanVal = cv::Scalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0);
const size_t inWidth = 300;
const size_t inHeight = 300;

std::vector<FaceDetectionResult> namespace_name::FaceDetection::detectFaceByOpenCVDNN(std::string filename, FaceDetectionModel model)
{        

    Net net;        
    cv::Mat frame = cv::imread(filename);
    cv::Mat inputBlob;
    std::vector<FaceDetectionResult> vec;


    if (frame.empty())
        throw std::exception("provided image file is not found or unable to open.");

    int frameHeight = frame.rows;
    int frameWidth = frame.cols;

    if (model == FaceDetectionModel::CAFFE)
    {            
        net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(caffeConfigFile, caffeWeightFile);
        inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, inScaleFactor, cv::Size(inWidth, inHeight), meanVal, false, false);
    }
    else
    {            
        net = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(tensorflowWeightFile, tensorflowConfigFile);
        inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, inScaleFactor, cv::Size(inWidth, inHeight), meanVal, true, false);
    }

    net.setInput(inputBlob, "data");
    cv::Mat detection = net.forward("detection_out");

    cv::Mat detectionMat(detection.size[2], detection.size[3], CV_32F, detection.ptr<float>());

    for (int i = 0; i < detectionMat.rows; i++)
    {            
        if (detectionMat.at<float>(i, 2) >= 0.5)
        {
            FaceDetectionResult res;
            res.faceDetected = true;
            res.confidence = detectionMat.at<float>(i, 2);

            res.x1 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 3) * frameWidth);
            res.y1 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 4) * frameHeight);
            res.x2 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 5) * frameWidth);
            res.y2 = static_cast<int>(detectionMat.at<float>(i, 6) * frameHeight);

            vec.push_back(res);
        }
#ifdef aDEBUG
        else
        {

            cout << detectionMat.at<float>(i, 2) << endl;

        }
#endif
    }                
    return vec;
}
```

In the above code, after face detection I assign confidence and co-ordinates of face detected in custom class `FaceDetectionResult`, which a simple class having bool and int,float members as required.

Function detect faces in the given image, but while playing with this I am doing comparison with `dlib's` HOG+SVM face detector, So first I am doing face detection by dlib and then same image path is passed to this function.

I found some images where dlib can easily find faces in the image but opencv didn't find a single face, for example look at below image:

[image: HOG+SVM]

As you can see HOG+SVM detected 46 faces in approx 3 sec., If I pass this same image to above function then opencv did not detect a single face in it. Why? Do I need any enhancements in above code? I am not saying that function does not detect faces for any image, it does, but for some images (like above) it could not not.

For ref:

I used https://pastebin.com/9rt9reNY this python program to detect faces using dlib.

Comment: I marked faces which are having confidence >= 0.5, for this image if I change it to 0.12 then also I found only 8 faces with 2 false positive.

Comment: I tried your code in some many faces images and works properly. I think [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/face-detection-opencv-dlib-and-deep-learning-c-python/) is also similar to your referece which I used before

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk have tried on provided image? As I said, it works very well but on some images it won't work at all.

Comment: I couldnt try your shared image cos it is not pure :). Maybe this is also a difference between the other models. Cos this model seems that it gives quick,speedy reults as I observed

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk here is the pure image :) source, if you are interested https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/03/14/31C8D17600000578-3473732-Obama_noted_Henry_s_SEC_record_of_more_than_22_000_rushing_yards-a-21_1457015357556.jpg

Comment: I think I found the problem. Just try to crop your image and try again :). It works fine. The problem I guess is about occlusion. I cropped half of image and tried it, the result is finding all faces. If It also works on your side, I think I can try to answer this question :)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk yes, you are correct. I cropped image to 481x576 (original was 962x576) and found 18 faces by opencv https://ibb.co/5h5kKpm and 19 by dlib HOG+SVM. Now can you open that secrete box and tell me what is the problem? I dont see all faces are hidden (occlusion) behind to other.

Answer (score 1):

After a deep search, unfortunately I couldn't find a good explanation to this problem. The reason why I tried to crop image is that I assumed there can be a maximum detected face number limit. It is also not about occlusion.

I tried some image examples which includes more than 20(appx.) faces and the results were the same but when I cropped those images(decrease the number of faces), program was able to find the faces.This is also not about the resolution(sizes) of the image because the images I tried had different sizes.

I also changed and tried the all parameters(iteration number, confidentThreshold etc.) but the result still wasn't the desired one.

My **assumption** but not the answer:

The program doesn't let to find the faces if image includes more than a maximum number(approximately 20)

As a solution for this question, we can divide the source image into 2 parts and find the rectangles for each one then can be pasted to source image.

**Note:** *After digging deeply on the internet, I couldnt find a topic related to this problem. I am also curious about the main reason causes this issue so any help will be appreciated. This post only includes my experiences and assumptions.*

Comment: OMG!! If, This is the reason then I am surprised. I also searched related to this but couldn't find anything, I will post it on opencv forum let's see what we get from there. But right now, thanks for throwing some focus on this based on your experience and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, inScaleFactor, cv::Size(inWidth, inHeight), meanVal, false, false);
```

by this line :

```
frameHeightinputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, inScaleFactor, cv::Size(inWidth, inHeight), meanVal, false, false);
```